# Cannot Restore Window from taskbar while executing

Tags: c#, windows, vba, winapi, vsto

I have an odd problem that is happening in my C# VSTO Excel app using Excel 2013 and Windows 8.1.

Whenever I am running a long-running task in my code and I switch to another application's window (for example I maximize Explorer or Chrome over Excel), I cannot restore the Excel Window from the task bar (nor via Alt+Tab). I have to minimize the other application's window to get focus back to Excel. I can't even get Show Desktop to work while the task is executing. This happens both when I show a progress form and when I am not showing a form at all.

What could be going on here?

Is there some win32 function that I can call via pinvoke before/while executing my task to get the taskbar functionality to work as expected?

VBA code that seems to be able to restore window while executing:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim i As Long, rng As Range

   Set rng = Range("A1")

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.Cursor = xlWait
   For i = 1 To 500000
     rng.Value2 = "test"
   Next i

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.Cursor = xlWait

   Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   Application.Cursor = xlDefault
End Sub
```

equivalent code in C# using VSTO where you can't restore the window while executing the code:

```
    public void RibbonButton_RunTest1(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        app.ScreenUpdating = false;
        app.EnableEvents = false;
        app.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlWait;
        //Run a long action that interacts with the Excel object model
        var worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) app.ActiveSheet;

        var range = worksheet.Range["A1"];
        for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
            range.Value2 = "test";

        app.ScreenUpdating = true;
        app.EnableEvents = true;
        app.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlDefault;
    }

    public void RibbonButton_RunTest2(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        var app = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
        app.ScreenUpdating = false;
        app.EnableEvents = false;
        app.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlWait;
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        app.ScreenUpdating = true;
        app.EnableEvents = true;
        app.Cursor = Excel.XlMousePointer.xlDefault;
    }
```

Comment: Probably just need to add DoEvents to your Excel code.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem since running equivalent code in vba does not have the taskbar restore issue. Besides doevents is bad coding practice.

Comment: Don't block the main thread

Comment: When using Excel all object model access must be done via the main thread, so any operation that reads or writes data from a worksheet must be done on the main thread. This problem doesn't happen on Excel 2007 though (which is MDI) so it could be specific to Excel 2013 (SDI)

Comment: @tttmack The time is spent in the Excel code? Or your code?

Comment: @David Heffernan I updated the question with simple code that reproduces the behavior. While running the VBA code, the window can be restored from the taskbar while the code is executing. While running the VSTO code, the window cannot be restored from the taskbar until the operation completes.